# Manually processing Interactive Grid that displays an Apex Collection

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid that displays the values of an apex collection and I want the "save" button on the interactive grid to save the values to the collection.

The sql query that pulls the data from the collection and into the IG looks like this:

```html
SELECT  c001 "Criteria ID", 
        c002 "Criteria Name", 
        c003 "Objective Evidence", 
        c004 "Required Evidence", 
        seq_id,
        c011 "Part A", 
        c012 "Part B", 
        c013 "Part C", 
        c014 "Part D", 
        c015 "Part E", 
        c016 "Part F", 
        c017 "Part G", 
        c018 "Part H", 
        c019 "Part I", 
        c020 "Part J" 
FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'TABLE_VIEW'
```

I added the following code to the "save interactive grid" processing:

```html
BEGIN
    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
        WHEN 'U' THEN
            APEX_COLLECTION.UPDATE_MEMBER (
                p_collection_name => 'TABLE_VIEW',
                p_seq => :seq_id,
                p_c001 => :CRITERIA_ID,
                p_c002 => :CRITERIA_NAME,
                p_c003 => :OBJECTIVE_EVIDENCE,
                p_c004 => :REQUIRED_EVIDENCE,
                p_c011 => :PART_A, 
                p_c012 => :PART_B, 
                p_c013 => :PART_C, 
                p_c014 => :PART_D, 
                p_c015 => :PART_E, 
                p_c016 => :PART_F, 
                p_c017 => :PART_G, 
                p_c018 => :PART_H, 
                p_c019 => :PART_I, 
                p_c020 => :PART_J 
            );
    END CASE;
END;
```

When I try to run it as it is I get the error:

```
ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you did but it works for me. This is what I did:

**Create collection**

```
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
p_collection_name => 'EMP_COLLECTION',
p_query => q'!SELECT * FROM emp!',
p_truncate_if_exists => 'YES'
);
```

**IG Query**

```
select seq_id, c001, c002 from apex_collections where collection_name =  'EMP_COLLECTION'
```

**IG Settings**
[image]

**Custom IG Process**

```
BEGIN
    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
        WHEN 'U' THEN
            APEX_COLLECTION.UPDATE_MEMBER (
                p_collection_name => 'EMP_COLLECTION',
                p_seq => :SEQ_ID,
                p_c001 => :C001,
                p_c002 => :C002
            );
    END CASE;
END;
```

I'm able to run the interactive grid, change a value and save. No errors.

The error you are getting seems to indicate there is an interactive grid native dml process executed. Can you run the page in debug and check what statement is throwing that error ? When you created the custom dml process, did you disable/delete the native interactive grid process ?

Comment: My IG settings match the ones you posted.  After running it in debug mode I found the following lines just before executing the code: `>>> APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS Table View - Save Interactive Grid Data` followed by `...Process "Table View - Save Interactive Grid Data" - Type: NATIVE_IG_DML`  Does this mean that I am still executing a native DML type?

Comment: I changed the Type of process to Execute code instead of Automatic Row Processing and the error goes away but now the row is removed from the IG after saving an edit made on it

Comment: If you use that custom code, you should remove the native ig process. My code works, I tested it. I suggest you replicate my code - it is on the sample emp table - and then debug yours to figure out why yours doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs across this problem I had two issues.  The first being the one that another user pointed out.  That I still had the Native IG DML enabled you can check if this is the case for you by running it in debug mode as I pointed out in the comments for Koen's response.  The second is that the names of my columns had spaces and didn't match what I had in the code.